# List slider script like spotify

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a jquery plugin that allows navigation horizontally in a list exactly how Spotify do it in the browser menu.

Screenshot : http://cl.ly/image/380x292d0a0n

The great thing here is that it is responsive and automatically reduce the amount of elements depending on window width.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will something like this work?

http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified

That one looks pretty responsive and you can customize it pretty much any way you want it.